# components of two unitary matrix multiply

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is as follows: If U is a unitary matrix, $$U=(u_1,...,u_n).$$ And if Q is a unitary matrix, $$Q=(q_1,...,q_n).$$
Then, I want to calculate this term $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n u_ju_j'q_jq_j'$.

Does $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n u_ju_j'q_jq_j'$ equal to 1??

Comment: If $u^{'}_{j}$ and $q^{'}_{j}$ are the conjugates of $u_j$ and $q_j$ respectively, then the sum would be n and not 1.

Comment: If U is a unitary matrix with $\{ u_1,...,u_n\}$ an orthonormal basis of $R^n$, then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n u_j u_j' =1$. Is it right? or it should be n?

Comment: You have $u_{j}u_{j}^{'}=1$ so, $\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_{j}u_{j}^{'}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}1=n$